# is there a command to "view the content of a .tar.Z" in UNIX / IBM AIX

Tags: unix, aix

(UNIX IBM AIX)
When I restore an environment sometimes I just need specific files from a specific directory and as it takes too long to restore and untar the restore I was wondering if there's a command that would list the content of the restore so at least I'll be sure that the files exist.

For now I just untar the restore and wait for hours and then take the files I need.

I already tried `wildcards` and `gtar -tvf`

`uncompress file.tar.Z|tar tvf -`

`uncompress file.tar.Z|tar xvf - /path/to/file`

`uncompress file.tar.Z|tar xvf - uncompress file.tar.Z|tar tvf - |grep wildcard`

returns with error file.tar.Z not a compressed file

`file file.tar.Z` : data or International Language text

this one works for me but only on files that don't exceed 150g in size gtar xvzf file.tar.Z path/ 
yet most of the files are above 900g

file blocks on fsize=-1

No results till now but I hope I to find something with your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to view the content of this file is:

```
uncompress file.tar.Z|tar tvf -
```

to extract particular file you can use the command:

```
uncompress file.tar.Z|tar xvf - /path/to/file
```

Be aware that you can't use wildcards with UNIX `tar`

If you want to use wildcard you should use something like:

```
`uncompress file.tar.Z|tar xvf -  `uncompress file.tar.Z|tar tvf - |grep `wildcard`
```

Also do not forget to update the `ulimit` so

```
file(blocks) 2097151
```

represent the size bigger than your tar file. The number is in 512 bytes blocks

Comment: Note that showing the contents of a big compressed tar file may take a long time because the whole file has to be uncompressed and read. When you know which files you need, the tar file has to be read again from the beginning to extract the files, but this time reading may be faster if it is cached from the first read operation.

Comment: @Bodo, OS cache most of file reading operation. And in this case the commands are connected via pipe so it's not need to cache

Comment: That's by design: tar-files don't have a central directory (unlike zip-files), meta-data and file-content is mixed together.

Comment: If it takes hours to extract the whole tar file (see question) it might be very big, so it depends on the available memory what the OS can hold in the cache.

Comment: @Bodo, cache will be in charge only it OP want to extract file by wildcard. Otherwise the entire file must be read. and no cache will be involved

Comment: it didn't work i get back an error as if the file isnt compressed (not a compressed file) 
this one works for me but only on files that don't exceed 150g in size 

gtar xvzf file.tar.Z path/

yet most of the files are above 900g

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI, please update your question with this information, also include the errors. And give us result of command `file file.tar.Z`

Comment: file blocks on fsize=-1

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI, what is the result of `file file.tar.Z`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov sorry i didn't understand what do you mean by the result of file file.tar.Z ....

Comment: execute this command: `file name_of_your.tar.Z` and paste the result in your question

Comment: @RomeoNinov the result is data or International Language text

Comment: @TarikMESSAOUDI, this mean its not compressed archive

Comment: @RomeoNinov to be honest i'm lost right now when i retreive the restore the size is less important than after i execute the gtar command ... in this case is there any way

Answer (score 2):

What about this command?

```
tar tvfz ...
```

The `t` means: show the contents without actually unzipping.

Comment: This will not work because (usually) UNIXes do not use GNU tar, so you do not have `z`

Comment: @RomeoNinov GNU tar seems to be available. Citation from the question: "I already tried wildcards and **gtar** -jtp2"

Comment: @Bodo, fine. But format `tvfz` may not work. IMHO the propper format is `tvzf`. Otherwise `z` may be counted as filename